# Unable to install linux-tools for perf

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, tools

I want to use [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), so I tried to install linux-tools-common with the command:

`sudo apt install linux-tools-common`

However I got this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35 linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-35-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/277 kB of archives.
After this operation, 833 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 463754 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-73.80) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1030.35
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to solve the problem by following the advice in the error message:

`sudo apt autoremove`

Which let to the next error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-5.15.0-73 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After running: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, I get the same error message as before:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35 linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-35-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/277 kB of archives.
After this operation, 833 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 463754 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-73.80) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1030.35
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-73.80_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8 Processor.

**EDIT:**
I tried to install: [perf-tools-unstable](https://installati.one/install-perf-tools-unstable-ubuntu-22-04/), but still get the same error message:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-5.15.0-73 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**SECOND EDIT:**
My repository configurations are:

```
$ apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | sort -u
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe
https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing/stable
https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jonmagon/crow-translate/ubuntu jammy/main
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu jammy/main
https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried [this](https://installati.one/install-perf-tools-unstable-ubuntu-22-04/)?

Comment: I did not know about this! Does perf-tools-unstable have the same functionalities as the regular perf from the linux-tools package?@SadaharuWakisaka ?

Comment: Why is someone proposing an "unstable" version? I would not recommend installing it. The output looks like some invalid or old repository has been added. linux-tools can be installed without any problems - if not using some "unstable" software.  Please list your repository configuration using `apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | sort -u`. Paste the result of that command on your question, **not** in the comments

Comment: Thank you for your advice, here's my rep conf @kanehekili

Comment: I have no idea, the google search returned unstable version. For me, the packages in the apt are trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `acpidebug` with its package `linux-intel-iotg-tools-common` which probably comes from one of the ppas or "foreign" repositories. So it clashes with the perf-tools (unstable or stable) package. You'll need to remove it before installing the latter package

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same issue and nothing helped. So i did this (in case of my kernel):

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-intel-iotg-5.15-tools-common
```

then:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This resolved the issue. My system:

```
Linux 5.15.0-91-generic #101~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 16 14:22:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```